# Outer join not working, only Null columns required in the query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created the below query to find out employees that do not exist in table  pay_person_pay_methods_f 
and pay_org_pay_methods_vl by using conidtion ORG_PAYMENT_METHOD_NAME is nul l. I have used old outer join for this since I am not familiar to the new one and the new one is giving me errors.

This below query is giving me more data... that is even if the values ORG_PAYMENT_METHOD_NAME is not null for them, it is fetching in this query. What can i change in this to make full proof ?

```
select * from 
(SELECT DISTINCT p.person_number, 
                paaf.assignment_number, 
                payroll_relationship_number, 
                PPPM.percentage, 
                PPPM.priority, 
                POPM.org_payment_method_name, 
                pppm.NAME, 
                To_char(PPPM.effective_start_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
                Effective_start_date, 
                pppm.payment_amount_type, 
                PPPM.amount 
FROM   per_all_people_f p, 
       pay_pay_relationships_dn ppr, 
       pay_person_pay_methods_f pppm, 
       per_all_assignments_m paaf, 
       pay_org_pay_methods_vl POPM 
WHERE  p.person_id = ppr.person_id 
       AND paaf.assignment_type NOT LIKE '%T%' 
       AND paaf.person_id = p.person_id 
      AND PAAF.EFFECTIVE_LATEST_CHANGE = 'Y'
       AND paaf.assignment_status_type LIKE 'ACTIVE%' 
       AND Trunc(sysdate) BETWEEN paaf.effective_start_date AND 
                                  paaf.effective_end_date 
       AND POPM.org_payment_method_id(+) = PPPM.org_payment_method_id
       AND ppr.payroll_relationship_id = pppm.payroll_relationship_id(+)  

       AND Trunc(sysdate) BETWEEN p.effective_start_date AND 
                                  p.effective_end_date 
       AND Trunc(sysdate) BETWEEN ppr.start_date AND ppr.end_date 
      AND Trunc(sysdate) BETWEEN POPM.effective_start_date(+) AND 
                                  POPM.effective_end_date(+) 

       AND Trunc(sysdate) BETWEEN pppm.effective_start_date(+) AND 
                                 pppm.effective_end_date(+)
                                  )
                                  where ORG_PAYMENT_METHOD_NAME is null
                                  order by person_number
```

Comment: Thanks @ERIC ! :) I will learn for sure !

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

I'm not sure you want the(+) on POPM and PPPM for your sysdates...

Doens't the (+) mean all records thus making it outer joins which could be causing you to get back more records than desired since it would include all POPM or all PPPM records when infact I think you just want all per_all_people?

Here's the SQL in the new form I believe...

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT p.person_number, 
                paaf.assignment_number, 
                payroll_relationship_number, 
                PPPM.percentage, 
                PPPM.priority, 
                POPM.org_payment_method_name, 
                pppm.NAME, 
                To_char(PPPM.effective_start_date, 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
                Effective_start_date, 
                pppm.payment_amount_type, 
                PPPM.amount 
  FROM per_all_people_f p
  LEFT JOIN pay_pay_relationships_dn ppr
    on p.person_id = ppr.person_id 
   AND Trunc(sysdate) BETWEEN p.effective_start_date AND p.effective_end_date 
   AND Trunc(sysdate) BETWEEN ppr.start_date AND ppr.end_date 
  LEFT JOIN pay_person_pay_methods_f pppm
    on ppr.payroll_relationship_id = pppm.payroll_relationship_id 
   AND Trunc(sysdate) BETWEEN pppm.effective_start_date AND pppm.effective_end_date

  LEFT JOIN per_all_assignments_m paaf
    ON paaf.person_id = p.person_id  
   AND paaf.assignment_type NOT LIKE '%T%' 
   AND PAAF.EFFECTIVE_LATEST_CHANGE = 'Y'
   AND paaf.assignment_status_type LIKE 'ACTIVE%' 
   AND Trunc(sysdate) BETWEEN paaf.effective_start_date AND paaf.effective_end_date 
  LEFT JOIN pay_org_pay_methods_vl POPM 
   ON POPM.org_payment_method_id = PPPM.org_payment_method_id
  AND Trunc(sysdate) BETWEEN POPM.effective_start_date AND POPM.effective_end_date
)
WHERE ORG_PAYMENT_METHOD_NAME is null
ORDER BY  person_number
```

Comment: THIS IS WORKING.. but even inactive employees are getting picked .. evrn though there is an active condition  paaf.assignment_status_type LIKE 'ACTIVE%'

Comment: this is still giving employees with data in pay_person_pay_methods_f

Comment: @Sree: please EDIT YOUR QUESTION, include example data for all tables, expected results, and the results you're getting. Otherwise people are just guessing. A properly filled in and working dbfiddle or sqlfiddle is worth an upvote. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious problem is the lack of a `(+)` in the following line:

```
AND POPM.org_payment_method_id(+) = PPPM.org_payment_method_id
```

It should read

```
AND POPM.org_payment_method_id(+) = PPPM.org_payment_method_id(+)
```

because you're trying (based on the other info in the query) to outer-join in the PAY_PERSON_PAY_METHODS_F table, and the lack of the trailing `(+)` on the second value in this comparison results in the join effectively being converted to an inner join.

Really, you need to learn the "new-style" ANSI joins. They've only been around for 29 years - I think it's safe to say they're not just a fad. :-)

If you reformat the query to get rid of the implied joins you get something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.PERSON_NUMBER, 
                paaf.ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER, 
                PAYROLL_RELATIONSHIP_NUMBER, 
                pppm.PERCENTAGE, 
                pppm.PRIORITY, 
                popm.ORG_PAYMENT_METHOD_NAME, 
                pppm.NAME, 
                TO_CHAR(pppm.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
                p.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE, 
                pppm.PAYMENT_AMOUNT_TYPE, 
                pppm.AMOUNT 
  FROM PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F p
  INNER JOIN PAY_PAY_RELATIONSHIPS_DN ppr
    ON ppr.PERSON_ID = p.PERSON_ID AND
       TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN ppr.START_DATE
                          AND ppr.END_DATE
  INNER JOIN PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_M paaf
    ON paaf.PERSON_ID = p.PERSON_ID AND 
       paaf.EFFECTIVE_LATEST_CHANGE = 'Y' AND
       paaf.ASSIGNMENT_STATUS_TYPE LIKE 'ACTIVE%' AND
       paaf.ASSIGNMENT_TYPE NOT LIKE '%T%' AND
       TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN paaf.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE 
                          AND paaf.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PAY_PERSON_PAY_METHODS_F pppm
    ON pppm.PAYROLL_RELATIONSHIP_ID  = ppr.PAYROLL_RELATIONSHIP_ID AND
       TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN pppm.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE
                          AND pppm.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
  LEFT OUTER JOIN PAY_ORG_PAY_METHODS_VL popm
    ON popm.ORG_PAYMENT_METHOD_ID = PPPM.ORG_PAYMENT_METHOD_ID AND
       TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN popm.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE
                          AND popm.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
  WHERE TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN p.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE
                           AND p.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE AND
        popm.ORG_PAYMENT_METHOD_NAME IS NULL
  ORDER BY p.PERSON_NUMBER
```